# sql to select top 10 records

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

I have the following table  (points):

```
    recno   uid   uname   points
    ============================
    1       a     abc      10
    2       b     bac      8
    3       c     cvb      12
    4       d     aty      13
    5       f     cyu      9
    -------------------------
    --------------------------
```

What I need is to show only the top ten records with by points (desc) and five records on each page.  I have following the SQL statement:

```
    select * from points where uid in(a,c) order by uid LIMIT 1, 5
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand...

Is that what you want:

select * from points order by points desct limit 5

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for the first page:

```
SELECT * FROM points p ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

for the second page:

```
SELECT * FROM points p ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 5, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute an SQL query to return a set number of pages, you'll have to implement some kind of pagination module or whatever equivalent there is for the scenario you're in and fetch `LIMIT 0, 5` for one then `LIMIT 5, 5` for the other.

With such few records it wouldn't be an issue but in a production scale environment selected all records then breaking those results down into pages would be a lot of unnecessary overhead, it's good practice to only select the data you need.