# select top 10 students from database

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sql to select top 10 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396073/sql-to-select-top-10-records)

Assuming you have one table with StuId, StuName, Subject, Grade. You are required to provide a subquery to return a list of honor students (top 10 percent), sorted by their grade point average.

for example, if I have 10 student whose average grade is 100,90,80,...10. 
It is required to output the first student name whose average is 100. Only one student grade is output. So I can't use limit 10

I am using mysql 5.1.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Stuname, TOP 10 Avg(Grade) as GPA 
  FROM Table 
GROUP BY Stuid 
ORDER BY GPA
```

The query is not correct because of the `TOP 10`. Checking MYSQL 5.1 reference, it does not support top 10.

According to comments, I dont think it can be resolved using one query, so I come up with a method:

```
F(conn){
Statement stmt;
int top10percnet = 0;
try{
stmt = conn.createStatement;
String query = "select CEIL(count(stuname)*10/100) as 10percent from grades";
ResultSet rs = stmt.execute(query);
while(rs.next()){
  top10percent = rs.getString("10percent");
}
query = "select stuname, avg(grade) as average from grades group by stuname order
by average desc limit " + Integer.toString(top10percnet);
rs=stmt.execute(query);
while(rs.next()){
   ...// output result
}
}
catch(SQLException e){
}



}
```

Comment: I'm curious, could you link to the MySQL documentation referencing the `TOP` clause?

Comment: My previous question requirement is not clear, so I edit it. I am not expecting the first 10 students, but the first 10% student. It might be one person, zero person.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
count = select CEIL(count(Stuname)*10/100) from table_name;
select Stuname from table_name ORDER BY GPA DESC limit count;
```

First query will return the 10% of the students.CEIL is used to convert it into integer.
Second query is to retrieve the data.
The count calculated from the first query is set as the limit to the second query.

Comment: Some advice, be a bit more elaborate so that other's can better understand your solution.

Answer (score 3):

### Update

Sounds like you want to incorporate a `HAVING` clause to limit the results to those scoring an average grade higher than 90.

Try

```
SELECT Stuid, Stuname, AVG(Grade) AS GPA FROM Table
GROUP BY Stuid, Stuname
HAVING AVG(GRADE) > 90
ORDER BY GPA DESC -- If you want highest-to-lowest. Thanks Bohemian
```

Comment: Sorry, wrong. This will give the LOWEST 10

Comment: @Bohemian Just going with the code in the OP

Comment: Code has the same problem in question too. -1 removed :) (u fixed it)

Comment: `HAVING`, nor AVG, addresses the percentage requirement.  I've asked the OP to revert changes, mark and answer & post a new question about the percentage.

Comment: @OMGPonies Yeah, I wasn't entirely sure what the OP was after. I see now they want the top 10% of all records found

Answer (score 3):

Use `LIMIT` and `DESC` order (ie highest to lowest):

```
select Stuname, Avg(Grade) as GPA
from Table
group by Stuid
order by 1 DESC -- Add DESC
LIMIT 10 -- Add LIMIT
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `order by GPA DESC`, and not `2`?

Comment: @Shurane MySQL supports column index in the `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: Either will work. Since SQL92, `group by` and `order by` can take the column number instead of the expression

Comment: @Shurane: This answer is using the ordinal value, based on the position in the SELECT clause.  It's valid, but not a recommended practice because if someone adds a column at the first or between the two existing columns -- the `ORDER BY` won't be the same, it'll order by whatever column is second in the list.

Comment: @Bohemian Can't remember if it's one of those magic MySQL things, but does the `GROUP BY` work if the column isn't part of the select?

Comment: In this case, there's only 2 columns, so I think we can live with it

Comment: Ahhh! yes @Phil - it should be `GROUP BY 1` - my bad. edited.

Comment: @Phil: MySQL (and SQLite) support [hidden columns in the GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).  However, the value of columns omitted will be arbitrary -- it can't be guaranteed

Comment: @Phil: The "hidden column" functionality is specifically for columns that are not stated in the `GROUP BY` or wrapped in an aggregate function (MAX, MIN, etc).

Answer (score 2):

`TOP` is SQL Server 2000+ specific; MySQL uses the `LIMIT` syntax -- neither are ANSI, only recently was the `FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY` made ANSI (DB2 is the only DB I know of that supports it).

Because you tagged the question as "mysql":

```
  SELECT t.stuname,
         AVG(t.grade) AS grade_avg
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.stuname
ORDER BY grade_avg DESC
   LIMIT 10
```

For SQL Server 2000+, the query would be:

```
  SELECT TOP 10
         t.stuname,
         AVG(t.grade) AS grade_avg
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.stuname
ORDER BY grade_avg DESC
```

`TOP` is always before the columns in the `SELECT` clause.  As of SQL Server 2005+, you can use brackets around the top value to allow you use a variable instead:

```
DECLARE @int_var INT
SET @int_var = 10

  SELECT TOP (@int_var)
         t.stuname,
         AVG(t.grade) AS grade_avg
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.stuname
ORDER BY grade_avg DESC
```

This allows you dynamically set the `TOP` without requiring dynamic SQL.

Comment: @SecureFish: Which is what the first query is for -- the database each query applies to is stated before each one...

Comment: The question is not clear when I post it the first time (Now it has been edited). It is not TOP 10 records, it is the top 10 percent records. For example, if you have 10 records, only the firs record will be output.

Comment: @SecureFish: So you realize your requirements are off, after you've gotten a few answers?  We aren't notified about updates to questions; out of respect, I suggest you revert your updates, choose an answer, and post another question to ask about getting the percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using LIMIT instead?

e.g.

```
select Stuname, Avg(Grade) as GPA from Table group by Stuid order by GPA limit 10
```

Comment: Won't work. This will give the LOWEST 10